# Finding length of clothes

Tags: linear-algebra, ratio, simple-functions

There are three types of clothes:

```
A- Rs. 1 for 5mtrs
B- Rs. 5 for 1mtr
C- Rs. 1 for 1.5mtrs
```

How much cloth is required for each type in mtrs, So that total for Rs. 5 we get total 5mtrs cloth?

Comment: So, I think, essentially you're trying to solve
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x + 5y + z = 5 \\
5x + y + \frac{3}{2}z = 5
\end{array}
\right.
$$
with $x,y,z\geq 0$ and $\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Suppose we take $x, y$ and $z$ metres of the cloth materials $A, B$ and $C$ respectively. Now, we have the following linear equations:
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{5} + 5y + \frac{2z}{3} & = 5\\
x + y + z & =5 \end{align}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: In the first equation, I think you mean ${x\over5}$ not ${x\over3}$.

Comment: @saulpsatz Thanks for pointing out that typo.

Answer (score 0):

Or, in other words, you want the solution to the system $$x+y+z=5,\,x+5y+z=5,$$ where the variables denote the length of each type of cloth respectively. Unless you know something else there are infinitely many solutions, and in each of these cases you'd have to do without cloth $B.$